# Push данных в двумерных массив?

Tags: vue.js

Как мне правильно пушать (name, topic, days) в массив studentIndex: []
Cпасибо!)

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#data-tag",
  data: {
   dataend: '',
   days: '',
   studentIndex: [
    {nameStudentIndex:"", topicStudentIndex: "", days: ""},
   ]
  },
  watch: {
   dataend(){
    this.deadline();
   }
  },
  methods: {
   deadline() {
    const msPerDay = 8.64 * Math.pow(10, 7);
    const abs = Date.parse(this.dataend) - Date.now();
    this.days = Math.ceil(abs/msPerDay);
   },
   addtoList() {
    studentIndex.push(this.nameStudentIndex, this.topicStudentIndex, this.days);
    console.log(studentIndex);
   }

  },
  computed: {
   сolorTag() {
         switch(true) {
            case this.days > 60: {
              return 'blue'
            }
            case this.days < 60 && this.days>14: {
              return 'yellow'
            }
            case this.days < 14: {
              return 'red'
            }
            }
   }
  } 
 })
```

```css
tab {
   width: 140px;
   height: 80px;
   
  }
  .red {background-color: red;}
  .yellow {background-color: yellow;}
  .blue {background-color: blue;}
  #rezult {
   background-color: #eee;
  }
```

```html
<div id="data-tag">
 <input type="text" placeholder="name" v-model="nameStudentIndex">
 <input type="text" placeholder="topic" v-model="topicStudentIndex">
 <input type="date" placeholder="дата окончания" v-model="dataend">
 <button @click="addtoList">Add</button>
 

 <div id="rezult" v-for="studentIndexes in studentIndex">
  <div>{{studentIndexes.nameStudentIndex}}</div>
  <div>{{studentIndexes.nameStudentIndex}}</div>
  <div> {{studentIndexes.days}} days</div>
  <div :class="`tab ${сolorTag}`"></div>
 </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
```

Comment: перефразируйте вопрос, так как суть вопроса вообще не ясна

Comment: ryzen сделал вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cоздать объект в объекте `data`:

```
newStudent: {}
```

к соответствующим полям формы добавить `v-model`

```
<input type="text" placeholder="name" v-model="newStudent.nameStudentIndex">
<input type="text" placeholder="topic" v-model="newStudent.topicStudentIndex">
```

Свойство `days` у вас формируется по событию выбора даты, вешаем на него обработчик.

```
<input type="date" placeholder="дата окончания" @change="deadline" v-model="dataend">
```

Это позволит запустить функцию `deadline` после выбора даты.
В теле которой, после вычислений, результат передаем свойству `days` объекта `newStudent`

```
this.newStudent.days = Math.ceil(abs / msPerDay);
```

После заполнения всех полей у вас будет объект `newStudent` с необходимыми свойствами

```
{ "nameStudentIndex": "asdsdasd", "topicStudentIndex": "asdasd", "days": 34 }
```

и вы можете его "запушить" в массив

Для наглядности привожу **пример**.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#data-tag",
  data: {
    dataend: '',
    days: '',
    newStudent: {},
    studentIndex: [{
        nameStudentIndex: 'name test',
        topicStudentIndex: 'topic test',
        days: 50
      },
      {
        nameStudentIndex: 'name test',
        topicStudentIndex: 'topic test',
        days: 13
      }
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    deadline() {
      const msPerDay = 8.64 * Math.pow(10, 7);
      const abs = Date.parse(this.dataend) - Date.now();
      this.newStudent.days = Math.ceil(abs / msPerDay);
    },
    addtoList() {
      this.studentIndex.push(this.newStudent);
      this.dataend = 0;
      Vue.set(this, 'newStudent', {});
    }
  },
  computed: {
    
    сolorTag() {
      return (days) => {
        switch (true) {
          case days > 60:
            {
              return 'blue'
            }
          case days < 60 && days > 14:
            {
              return 'yellow'
            }
          case days < 14:
            {
              return 'red'
            }
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.tab {
  height: 100%;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.box {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: #eee;
}

.box>div {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="data-tag">
  <input type="text" placeholder="name" v-model="newStudent.nameStudentIndex">
  <input type="text" placeholder="topic" v-model="newStudent.topicStudentIndex">
  <input type="date" placeholder="дата окончания" @change="deadline" v-model="dataend">
  <button @click="addtoList">Add</button>
  <pre>{{ newStudent }}</pre>
  <div id="rezult" v-for="(studentIndexes, index) in studentIndex" :key="index">
    <div class="box">
      <div>{{studentIndexes.nameStudentIndex}}</div>
      <div>{{studentIndexes.nameStudentIndex}}</div>
      <div> {{studentIndexes.days}} days</div>
      <div class="tab" :class="[сolorTag(studentIndexes.days)]"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
```